# css acts right only when var_dump is present

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got problem with my layout. I am using bootstrap v3 and Nette framework.

I want ROW to have full height of window, but it's shorter unless there's var_dump present

CSS

```
.mainRow {
    height: calc(100% - 180px)!important;
    min-height: calc(100% - 180px)!important;
    max-height: calc(100% - 180px)!important;
```

HTML

```
<div class="row mainRow">
            <div class="col-md-10 bordered mainCol">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

without var_dump .mainRow is long as a content, with var_dump it works like a charm

EDIT: problem solved by using vh instead of %, 
thanks to Teuta Koraqi

Comment: Try to add vh instead of %!

Comment: yeah that helped me. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)